# Run function once I know object key exists on audio element in Angular

Tags: angular, html5-audio

I have been out in the ocean on this, possibly because I don't know the correct terms to search for. I need to change values on a sound element that only exists once it is playing. I am using a library pizzicato.js my variable 'this.pizzi' works the same as an html5 audio element. I can wrap it in a setTimeout to do this but this is obviously not a best practice. Using a callback doesn't seem to time this correctly either.

The error:
 Cannot set property 'onended' of undefined
[image]

```js
 this.initPizzi(this.effectsSettings, () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.pizzi.sourceNode.onended = () => {
              this.nextTrack();
            };
          }, 15000);
```

I am further confused that when I add an if check to make sure it has the key 'sourceNode' it still gets through and throws the error.  Here is more of the relevent code, any tips are appreciated, I know its a mess but I want to improve.

```js
private initPizzi(effectsSettings: EffectsSettings, callback?: Function): void {
    if (this.pizzi) {
      delete this.pizzi;
    }

    const pizzi = new Pizzicato.Sound({
      source: 'file',
      options: {
        path: this.rootDir + this.playlist[this.playlistPosition].path,
        volume: effectsSettings.volume
      }
    }, function () {
      const reverb = new Pizzicato.Effects.Reverb({
        time: 5,
        decay: 0.8,
        reverse: false,
        mix: effectsSettings.reverbMix
      });
      pizzi.addEffect(reverb);
      pizzi.play();

      pizzi.sourceNode.playbackRate.value = effectsSettings.speed;
    });
    this.pizzi = pizzi;
    this.currentSong$.emit(this.playlist[this.playlistPosition]);
    this.isPlaying$.emit(true);
    this.isLoading$.emit(false);

    callback();
  }
```

The prototype is here:
https://slomo.world

github for the project here:
https://github.com/Bokeefe/sloMoPlayer

Answer (score 0):

You can store the initial value of the object and then setup `ngDoCheck()` which will trigger when anything in your component changes. Then compare the old value with the new value - if they are not the same, call your method.

```
initialValue: string = '';

ngOnInit(){
  this.initialValue = JSON.stringify(this.pizzi);
}

ngDoCheck(){
  if(this.initialValue !== JSON.stringify(this.pizzi)){
     //actions
  }
}
```